# About the liouville equation $\Delta u = - \lambda e ^{u}$ on compact manifold with dimension $>2 $

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-equations

I want to ask about the liouville equation $\Delta u = - \lambda e ^{u}$ on compact manifold with dimension $>2 $.

There are many studies on this equation on Riemannian surface (dimension = 2), for example, [Kazdan and Warner](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ekazdan/642S16/KW-Gauss1-Annals1974.pdf), but there is no paper studing the higher dimension case except this: [E. N. Dancer and Alberto Farina](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-04/S0002-9939-08-09772-4/S0002-9939-08-09772-4.pdf). But they focused on the global solution
$$\tag{1}\begin{equation}\label{A1}
-\Delta u=e^u \quad \text { on } \mathbb{R}^N, \quad N \geq 2
\end{equation}$$
**which are stable outside a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^N$.**

Given a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ (possibly unbounded), a solution $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ of the equation $-\Delta u=e^u$ is said to be stable outside a compact set $\mathcal{K} \subset \Omega$ if
$$
\forall \psi \in C_c^1(\Omega \backslash \mathcal{K}) \quad Q_u(\psi):=\int_{\Omega \backslash \mathcal{K}}|\nabla \psi|^2-e^u \psi^2 \geq 0 .
$$
In particular, when $\mathcal{K}$ is the empty set, the solution $u$ is said to be stable in $\Omega$.

And their conclusion is that:

**Theorem 1** Let $3 \leq N \leq 9$. Equation (\ref{A1}) does not admit any $C^2$ solution stable outside a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

**Theorem 2** For $N=2$ the equation (\ref{A1}) admits radial solutions stable outside a compact set. On the other hand, for every $N \geq 10$ the equation (\ref{A1}) possesses a radial stable solution.

I'm confused that why they focused on the **stable** solution instead of directly considering the Dirichlet problem? Are there some essential difficulties about the Dirichlet problem on higher dimension? For **Theorem 1**, we can take $\mathcal{K}$ as an empty set in $\Omega$, then there is no stable solution in $\Omega$, but what about the solution which is unstable?

And when $N \ge 10$, equation ($\ref{A1}$) possesses a radial stable solution, does is this means that if our domain $\Omega$ is radial symmetry and the boundary condition is also radial symmetry we can get the existence of the radial symmetry of the solution to the Dirichlet problem?

**Update:**
I just learned that this is called Gelfand problem, that for unit ball of dimension N
$$
 \begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
-\Delta u & =\lambda e^u & \text { in } B \\
u & =0 & \text { on } \partial B
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
$$

- For $N \geq 10$, there exists a unique solution for each $\lambda \in\left(0, \lambda^*\right)$.
- For $3 \leq N \leq 9$, the problem has
- a unique solution for $\lambda$ sufficiently small,
- finitely many solutions for $\lambda \neq 2(N-2)$,
- more than any given number of solutions for $\lambda$ sufficiently close to $2(N-2)$,
- infinitely many solutions for $\lambda=2(N-2)$,
- two solutions for $\lambda$ close to $\lambda^*$, and
- a unique solution for $\lambda=\lambda^*$.
- For $1 \leq N \leq 2$, the problem has exactly two solutions for every $\lambda \in\left(0, \lambda^*\right)$ and a unique one for $\lambda=\lambda^*$.

Here extremal parameter. For $1 \leq N \leq 9, \lambda^*>2(N-2)$ (for $N=1, \lambda^* \simeq 0.88$, for $N=2, \lambda^*=2$ and for $\left.N=3, \lambda^* \simeq 3.32\right)$. For $N \geq 10, \lambda^*=2(N-2)$.

The proof highly relied on its radial symmetry (transforming to ODE), I don't know how to generalize this result onto the manifold.